# Ajax.org compared to YUI, Ext JS, etc

Tags: extjs, comparison, yui, javascript-framework

Has anyone got experience of ajax.org's Platform?  It looks great but I'm surprised how little info there is in the web about it.  Specifically, I'm interested in how it compares to ext.js and YUI or other frameworks.  I'm also starting to use server side javascript so any thoughts on their O3 stuff would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comparing Ajax.org & Ext JS**

I don't have any experience with Ajax.org but going through the site and documentation. I feel Ext JS 4, the latest version is much ahead in terms of functionality and features offered. Have a look at the number of components available with Ext JS.

For example, take Grids. Ext JS provides a feature rich control with filtering, grouping, paging and much more. Ajax.org seems to have very basic controls compared to Ext JS.

You also need to look at community and how fast you can get help. Ext JS is very popular now and easy to get community help. Ajax.org's forum is not active comparing to Ext JS.

Now, you might consider Ext JS a fail when it comes to licensing. Ajax.org is using LGPL where as Ext JS uses GPLv3. At times, this becomes a deciding factor when choosing frameworks.

**Comparing Ajax.org & YUI**

When comparing YUI and Ajax.org, YUI wins because of community. YUI also provides more functionality compared to Ajax.org, so I would prefer YUI. Looking at the license, YUI uses a BSD License. BSD is much more permissive when compared to LGPL or GPL.

**Ajax.org O3 Feature**

O3 platform look interesting. Ext JS and YUI stays purely client side and there is attempt to give or take server side programming. I am not sure how useful the O3 platform is, but If you plan to use it, the community would love to hear you experience! But, the platform seems to be in pre-alpha. I will not advice using it to build applications that will go to production soon.